# add a root element using xmldocument in C#.net

Tags: c#, xmldocument

I need to create an XML file using an xmldocument object in C#.

How can I add  a root element like:

```
 book:aaaa xsi:schemalocationchemaLocation="http://www.com"
```

Comment: And the example code in the MSDN documentation doesn't help?

Answer (score 19):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement elem = doc.CreateElement("book", "aaaa", "http://www.com");
doc.AppendChild(elem);
```